# How can I get system information from the command line?

Tags: ssh, command-line, distributions

Sometimes when I log on to a system via SSH (for example to the production server), I have such privileges that there can install some software, but to do that I need to know the system with which I am dealing.

I would be able to check how the system is installed there.

Is there a way from the CLI to determine what distribution of Unix/Linux is running?

Comment: Yes, thank you @muru, I didn't know about it sooner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
uname -a
```

It will give you output such as:

```
Linux debianhost 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) i686 GNU/Linux
```

You can also use:

```
cat /etc/*release*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: In my case `uname -a` works, but `cat /etc/*relase*` it's not.

Comment: Ok. My bad, I thought that command would work across all distributions, I was apparently wrong!

Comment: But it's good that you have entered it, because certainly in many cases it may be helpful...

Answer (score 2):

To get the hostname, kernel version, and other useful information about the system:

```
uname -a
```

To get the version of the Linux distribution, there is not an unique command. Every distro implements it differently. On Debian and Ubuntu:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

On Red Hat:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
cat /etc/lsb-release
lsb_release -a
```

On Fedora:

```
cat /etc/fedora-release
```

Comment: Systems using `systemd` should also have an [`/etc/os-release`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) file.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux you can try lsb_release command which provides Linux Standard Base and distro specific information. Try:

```
lsb_release -d
```

Also check for other options in `man` page

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered a [couple](https://superuser.com/questions/348192/query-what-linux-unix-distribution-youre-using-from-the-command-line) of [times](https://superuser.com/questions/11008/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-im-running) over on SuperUser with the usual tricks already mentioned here. But [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/348234/329160) has a novel method I quite like:

```
python -c "import platform; print platform.dist()"
```

Note this only works if Python 2.3 or later is available and is no longer available in Python 3.8.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, but notice that it is deprecated since Python 3.5 and will be removed in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

**In a concise way you can do it like this** (thanks to [@daemontosh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330850/185096) answer):

```
lsb_release -a
```

...show all the information.

**Another concise way to get information is** (thanks to [@HeathRaftery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493036/185096) and [@JourneymanGeek](https://superuser.com/a/348198/661968) answers):

```
cat /proc/version
```

but there are many Unixes that don't support the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this problem can also be solved using [Python and the platform module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/platform.html) (thanks to @HeathRaftery):

Using `platform()` function:

```
python -c 'import platform; print platform.platform()'
# Linux-4.9.0-8-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.6
```

> Returns a single string identifying the *underlying platform with as much useful information as possible*.

Or using `uname()` function:

```
python -c 'import platform; print platform.uname()'
# ('Linux', 'debian', '4.9.0-8-amd64', '#1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27)', 'x86_64', '')
```

> Fairly portable uname interface. Returns a `namedtuple()` containing six attributes: `system`, `node`, `release`, `version`, `machine`, and `processor`.